# Does Ruby cache the result of a method that will evaluate to the same result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

Does Ruby cache the result of a method so that it does not need to evaluate it twice if it is called twice?

I am working in Rails, so for example, I could do the following where I store the result of a param passed into a Rails controller in a variable like so:

```
def foo_bar_method
  case param[:foobar]
  when 'foo' then 'bar'
  when 'bar' then 'baz'
  else 'barbaz'
end

result = foo_bar_method
puts result
puts result
```

This way I am only evaluating the `foo_bar_method` once. Does Ruby cache the result of this method (or does Rails do this)? Is it faster to use the code shown above, or will the following code result in the same performance?

```
def foo_bar_method
  case param[:foobar]
  when 'foo' then 'bar'
  when 'bar' then 'baz'
  else 'barbaz'
end

puts foo_bar_method
puts foo_bar_method
```

Comment: It will cache SQL queries but I don't think the result of the above method will be cached.

Comment: Note: in order to do this, Ruby would have to determine whether the method is referentially transparent, which is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby does not cache method results, because hardly any ruby function can be called a pure function and the compiler cannot tell whether the value changes or not due to ruby being dynamic as hell. For example this function:

```
def four
  2 + 2
end
```

might seems to be constant in time. Well, not if you do that:

```
class Fixnum
  def +(other)
    self * other - 3
  end
end
```

Well, obviously doing so is probably the worst thing you could do, but the fact is that you can do that.

In your two examples there will be no measurable performance gains, however in many cases it is a standard way of writing your code (execute once and store to variable).

When you are sure you are dealing with a function that will always yield same result, you can cache it using instance variable like this:

```
def foo_bar_method
  @foo_bar_method ||= 
    case param[:foobar]
      when 'foo' then 'bar'
      when 'bar' then 'baz'
      else 'barbaz'
    end
end
```

Assuming this is a method in your controller, it is safe to assume this value will not change in the controller lifetime (as each request uses different instance of the controller), so caching might make some sense especially for heavier calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby will not cache the result of a method. You can add in memoization yourself if you want to do it yourself though. There are a number of ways of doing this and several gems. Just depends on what you need (ie. argument handling, etc.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization